# Am I better off with NY's 529 plan? (Maryland resident)

Tags: united-states, investing, 529-plan, education-savings, maryland

Maryland resident here.

We'll be opening some 529 plans for our kids (ages 4.5, 2.5, and 1), and I'm wondering how to determine if we're better off with the in-state plan or another state's plan.

We're planning to save a minimum of $70,000 for each child (although we may invest more heavily) to fund a mix of community college and off-campus living at in-state public schools. Of particular interest is NY's plan, as I like the expense ratio and Vanguard investment options. 
Some details:

**MD:**

- Investments by TRowe Price
- 0.81% expense ratio
- $2500 tax deduction/kid (~5% state tax rate)
- Past performance ~6.5% (I know this doesn't predict future returns)

**NY:**

- Investments by Vanguard
- 0.16% expense ratio
- No tax deduction
- Past performance ~8.5% (I know this doesn't predict future returns)

Thoughts on how to determine the preferable plan?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's hard to argue with a guaranteed ~5% savings on the portion that could be deducted, but to save 70k per child you'll be contributing far more than $2,500 per year.

So in that case I think I'd use Maryland's system for $7,500 per year to maximize the tax benefit, then go with New York's plan for the rest of your contributions each year for the better investment options.

Comment: Interesting idea - I hadn't thought of that. (Although now that you bring it up, it seems like a very common sense solution). Thanks!